# Ambulance dataset needed

Tags: datasets

Could I get a dataset that can classify ambulances? 
I have searched everywhere, but, couldn't seem to get hold of a set of annotated images for ambulances.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here.

Looked at the Open Image Dataset by Google @ https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html

They provide image-level labels, object bounding boxes, object segmentation masks, and visual relationships.